# Mozilla Firefox UI turned white from black after PC restart

Tags: windows-10, firefox

My firefox used to follow the windows 10 theme, which on my PC is black. Like this:

[image]

Now after computer restart, Firefox turned white:

[image]

Where can I revert this change? It shines so bright it makes my eyes hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the Light theme is being applied. Go to `about:addons` and in Themes check which is enabled. If Default theme is no longer working for you and syncing with the operating system color scheme, enable Dark theme.

[image: Themes]